# Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers

Tags: discussion

See the discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?cb=1).

The gist:

> We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score. 
>  [...] 
> Seeing that some sites do not want to unpin the accepted answer, we decided to move forward with the status quo and not to change the default behaviour on existing sites. If you think unpinning the accepted answer on your site makes sense, please do the following:
>
> 1. Start a meta discussion on your per-site meta.
>
>     [...]

---

For reference, as of Oct 1, 1:15am UTC, ECON.SE has [215 questions whose accepted answers are not the highest voted](https://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/edit/1474651#resultSets). This amounts to about 2% of the currently answered (or more precisely, non-unanswered) questions.

---

Edit: 
Feel free to post differently worded answers, in the end we will only aggregate the Yay or Nay parts.

Answer (score 4):

I like that accepted answers are on top, let's keep it that way.

It is possible that I like this because if my answer is accepted it gets more visibility and is likely to get more votes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like that accepted answers are on top, let's unpin them.

It is possible that I hate this because if another answer is accepted it gets more visibility and is likely to get more votes than my objectively better answer.

Comment: On the one hand, voters are not always right, and may upvote some wrong answer. On the other hand, an accepted answer means the asker (as one voter) liked an answer. We probably should avoid this very very mild voter dictatorship, maybe. I do not really have a strong opinion on this issue honestly, but lean towards unpinning the accepted answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the second sentence from both this answer and the other one, to reduce the possibility for bias.

Comment: @user1271772 Oh, to live in a world without bias <3 But I don't mind if someone posts differently worded answers, in the end we will only aggregate the Yay or Nay parts.